# Intel Graphics driver install Ubuntu

Tags: intel-graphics

I'm using an Intel UHD Graphics 605.

That's part of the output of `lspci -v`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 605 [8086:3185] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1201]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

What do I need to install so that Ubuntu sees it? The computer is extremely laggy and hangs up or locks up with multiple windows open.

I looked at Intel's support page and I was unable to find a Linux download.

Answer (score 2):

The Intel Graphics Driver should be installed as part of the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` driver package by default. To make sure you have it please run

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

If the driver is installed but Ubuntu can't see it try installing mesa-utils by running

```
sudo apt install mesa-utils
```

Comment: I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04, ran both commands and am still experiencing the same problem as the thread starter :/

Answer (score 0):

This is weird it shows me what graphics I have but I don’t have installed Mesa-utils. I’ve ram the command and it started to install

Comment: The answer is not clear and needs more details for example mention the exact commands that worked for you and list of softwares on the system before and those you newly installed.